# How to apply TLS support to PJSIP for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, voip, pjsip

I am creating a VoIP application for IOS.
i am using the pjsip open source libraries for this .
I am able to connect when i configure the pjsip to UDP .
But i always get error code 171060 [Error creating transport: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT) [status=171060]]

I get it that somewhere I am making mistake while configuring the file settings for TLS.
This is what i am doing.

```
pjsua_transport_config cfg;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
    cfg.port = 5061;
    cfg.tls_setting.ca_list_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ca_list" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // location of cacert.pem

    cfg.tls_setting.cert_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"certificate" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // location of cacert.pem

    cfg.tls_setting.privkey_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pvkey" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); //

    cfg.tls_setting.password = pj_str("myPassword");
    cfg.tls_setting.verify_client = PJ_TRUE;
    cfg.tls_setting.verify_server = PJ_TRUE;
    cfg.tls_setting.method = PJSIP_TLSV1_METHOD;

    //
    NSLog(@"******TLS********");
    //pjsua_transport_id  transport_id = 1;
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS , &cfg, NULL);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
```

I have searched up and down on google on how to resolve this issue but i haven't come across any concrete solution thus far.
Please if anyone knows can you help me??

Comment: Did you compile pjsip with TLS support ?

Comment: @juned Yes i have compiled pjsip with openSSL enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
The newly created frameworks were not getting added.
And were not FAT libs so the problem rose.

Comment: Which framework was not added. please let me know . I am stuck in the same issue

Comment: If you have generated PJSIP libs .. then check if the header files are getting added. 
and also merge the libraries which support different arch e.g. armv7s, armv7, arm64
then merge those libs together.. and then add them..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089090/pjsip-tls-not-enable-for-iphone/36897236#36897236 

check this answer

Comment: How do i add in existing pjsip library ?

Comment: @RushangPrajapati why don't you go for webrtc now? this seems a little obsolete..

Comment: Hi @saurabh_s, I am facing same issue. I used vialerSIP Pod and able to connect calls via UDP and TCP but not TLS. Could you please guide me some process

Comment: No idea buddy. If it uses PJSIP internally then follow the exact procedure to create framework files and headers. and drag and drop them in your project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089090/pjsip-tls-not-enable-for-iphone/36897236#36897236 Check this answer there are steps mentioned