# Open SSL and TLS issue in iOS for Pjsip

Tags: ios, openssl, tls1.2, pjsip

I am using below code to configure TLS.
I had enable to in config_site.h file

## define PJ_HAS_SSL_SOCK   1

```
pjsua_transport_config cfg;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
    cfg.port = 5061;
    cfg.tls_setting.ca_list_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ca_list" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // location of cacert.pem

    cfg.tls_setting.cert_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"certificate" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); // location of cacert.pem

    cfg.tls_setting.privkey_file = pj_str((char*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pvkey" ofType:@"pem"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); //

    cfg.tls_setting.password = pj_str("myPassword");
    cfg.tls_setting.verify_client = PJ_TRUE;
    cfg.tls_setting.verify_server = PJ_TRUE;
    cfg.tls_setting.method = PJSIP_TLSV1_METHOD;

    //
    NSLog(@"******TLS********");
    //pjsua_transport_id  transport_id = 1;
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS , &cfg, NULL);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
```

Reference Link :
[How to apply TLS support to PJSIP for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651002/how-to-apply-tls-support-to-pjsip-for-ios)

I am using Pod "pjsip" : pjsip 2.7.1 version
https://cocoapods.org/pods/pjsip

I cannot see the logs :

```
...
checking for OpenSSL installations..
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... no
aconfigure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
aconfigure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for ERR_load_BIO_strings in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... yes
OpenSSL library found, SSL support enabled
...
```

I am getting error :

```
Error creating transport: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT) [status=171060]
```

Comment: I am getting the same on Android. Have you solved it?

Comment: openSSL is silently disable in pjsip. so you need to compile the library will openssl and then do the setting accordingly for TLS6(with ipv6) and or TLS(ipv4)

Comment: Yes. I was able to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: What was the issue for you?

Comment: I missed OpenSSL while compiling PJSIP

Comment: Are you able to implement different settings as per ipv6 and ipv4 connections ?

Comment: Do you have problem with calling on ipv6?

Comment: I had fixed that by changing name server and transport by TLS to TLS6. But that make me initialize sip every time I change the network from IPV4 to IPV6

Comment: Hi @iosdeveloper, can you explain me step-by-step flow. I am facing same issue. Unable to connect Via TLS